# Gaining illicit access to file system through file managers on Android

Tags: android-permissions

While experimenting with URIs that various Android file managers return from an intent with ACTION_GET_CONTENT, I found out something strange, that seems to me a major security problem, unless there is something that I misunderstand:

Both OI File Manager and ES File Explorer return URIs in the format "content://authority/path" where authority is "org.openintents.filemanager" or "com.estrongs.files" respectively, and path the file system path to the file.

Now when I create content URIs with these two authorities and use them in an app that does not have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and never has presented any file picking dialog with ACTION_GET_CONTENT to the user, I can use these URIs to read the file contents without any security exception being raised. Thus by querying if one of these apps is present, an attacker could read any file on external storage whose name he is able to guess or construct without the user having granted this permission.

In light of these findings, do these apps fail to handle access to their content providers correctly and should be considered a major security threat for Android users, or is there some flaw in the Android permission architecture itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out in the mean time that in the case of OI File Manager this has been reported and fixed:
http://blog.k3170makan.com/2014/02/path-disclosure-vulnerability-in-io.html
https://github.com/openintents/filemanager/commit/78ffa735924292e541f3b7f20ead605f053f0df4

Unfortunately the version published on F-Droid is still vulnerable.